# Why does the loop start after I enter the first value for team A even though it's less than 15?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

Why does the loop start after I enter the first value for team A even though it's less than 15?
After I enter the first value it doesn't go to the next loop where I am supposed to enter the value again until it reaches 15.

```
team_a = int(input("Please enter the score for team A: ")) 
team_b = int(input("Please enter the score for team B: "))  
team_a_score = 0 
team_b_score = 0 
Round = 0  
total_score = 15  

while total_score>team_a_score:

  team_a_score+=team_a 

  if total_score<team_a_score: 
  break 
print("the game is over")
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're expecting the behavior to be here. Do you want the loop to always be skipped? Why are you breaking out of the loop in almost the exact same situations where the loop condition would fail anyway (excluding the situation where `total_score` exactly equals `team_a_score`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you enter values only one time.
If you want to enter values in loop it should look like this:

```
team_a_score = 0 
team_b_score = 0 
Round = 0  
total_score = 15  

while total_score>team_a_score:
    team_a = int(input("Please enter the score for team A: ")) 
    team_b = int(input("Please enter the score for team B: "))  
    team_a_score+=team_a 

    if total_score<team_a_score: 
        break 
print("the game is over")
```

Comment: oh it worked, thank you so much! anouther quick question. I need to work with both values can I add  them to while loop? e.g while tota_score>team_a_score, team_b_score: ?

Comment: You can write it like that: `while (total_score>team_a_score and total_score>team_b_score):` Use `and` or `or` its depend on what you want

Comment: I'm going to try it, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

there should be a space before  break, your intention was wrong! Corrected it

```
team_a = int(input("Please enter the score for team A: ")) 
team_b = int(input("Please enter the score for team B: "))  
team_a_score = 0 
team_b_score = 0 
Round = 0  
total_score = 15  

while total_score>team_a_score:

  team_a_score+=team_a 

  if total_score<team_a_score: 
   break 
print("the game is over")
```

Comment: there should be a space before  break, your intention was wrong! Corrected it

Comment: Don't explain the code in a comment, put that in your answer itself!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask the input inside your loop ?

```
team_a_score = 0
total_score = 15  

while total_score > team_a_score:

  team_a = int(input("Please enter the score for team A: ")) 

  team_a_score += team_a 

print("the game is over")
```

Comment: I thought it would work in a loop even when the output was out of the loop, but now I know, thank you!